# why do designer use Div with Clear class?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Need to know why it is used and how it helps ? 
Is it a good practice ?

If any example explaining would be great.

e.g :

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Css :

```
.clear{
    width:100%;
    height:0px;
    clear:both;
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them. The clear property applies to both floating and non-floating elements.

Comment: When applied to non-floating blocks, it moves the border edge of the element down until it is below the margin edge of all relevant floats. This movement (when it happens) causes margin collapsing not to occur.

Comment: When applied to floating elements, it moves the margin edge of the element below the margin edge of all relevant floats. This affects the position of later floats, since later floats cannot be positioned higher than earlier ones.

Comment: OK is it like, If applied to a element It wont float to floating element and shifts down ?

Comment: Yes, kinda. Check the duplicate question.

Comment: Let me explain it in words: when element has float left or right, it's parent lose height, and behaves like has a height of 0, clearing restores the height of parent element, so it is always as high as the highest element inside it.

Comment: @DariuszSikorski I guess this is something else. In this case I use Position relative and overflow hidden to parent element. It takes the height of highest element. I get it what you wanted to say, came across this many times.